# Why apache camel does not consume jms messages concurrently when queue is not empty

Tags: jms, apache-camel

apache-activemq-5.8.0, apache-camel-2.12.3

I'm trying to achieve concurrent jms messages consumption. Consumer's endpoint has the next parameters set:

```
from(
 "lala:queue:testConcurrentConsumers?asyncConsumer=true&concurrentConsumers=5&maxConcurrentConsumers=6")
    .process(new Processor() {

      @Override
      public void process(
          final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("sleep: " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("woke up: " + exchange.getIn().getBody());
      }

    });
```

When queue does not exist on broker -- everything is ok and the further sent jms messages are processed concurrently with 5 up to 6 consumer threads

But if queue exists on broker while starting CamelContext, only 5 consumers are created and they process messages sequentially one by one (it looks like only single thread used instead of thread pool with 5-6 threads)

What am I doing wrong with parameters?

The only thing looking similar I've found over the internet about such problem is http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/ActiveMQ-asyncConsumer-problem-td5744405.html

Comment: I've found out how to configure consumer:
`?asyncConsumer=true&transacted=true&maxConcurrentConsumers=6` which turns off caching or `?asyncConsumer=true&maxConcurrentConsumers=6&cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE`

Comment: I had the same problem, but using `transacted=true` only partially fixed the problem for me. First one message was read from the queue, then after it completed, the rest of the messages processed concurrently. Using `cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE` worked for me.

Comment: Actually scratch that. Using `cacheLevelName=CACHE_NONE` produces the same behavior, one message read off first, then the rest processed concurrently. Still better than all being processed sequentially.